# MySQL unable to update table in cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here am going update table in a store procedure, for example:

```
lg    chr    lgAndMarker(result column)
D1a   Chr01  D1a(1)
```

Here what i mean is update current table `lgAndMarker` column through `chr` and `lg` column, using cursor to loop such table and update column in repeat clause, below is the store procedure:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE addLgAndMarker;
CREATE PROCEDURE addLgAndMarker()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE lg_ VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE chr_ VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE id_ INT(11);
    DECLARE lgAndMarker_ VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE ergodic INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE updateLgAndMarker CURSOR FOR SELECT id, lg, chr FROM chrlg;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET ergodic = 0;
    OPEN updateLgAndMarker;
    REPEAT
      FETCH updateLgAndMarker INTO id_, lg_, chr_;
      IF locate('Chr0', chr_) > 0 THEN
        SET chr_ = replace(chr_, 'Chr0', '');
        SET lgAndMarker_ = concat(lg_, '(', chr_, ')');
      ELSEIF locate('Chr', chr_) > 0 AND locate('Chr0', chr_) = 0 THEN
        SET chr_ = replace(chr_, 'Chr', '');
        SET lgAndMarker_ = concat(lg_, '(', chr_, ')');
      ELSE
        SET lgAndMarker_ = concat(lg_, '(', chr_, ')');
      END IF;
      SELECT chr_, lgAndMarker_, id_;
      UPDATE chrlg SET lgAndMarker = lgAndMarker_ WHERE id = id_;
      COMMIT ;
    UNTIL ergodic = 0 END REPEAT ;
    CLOSE updateLgAndMarker;
  END;
```

but what the result like this:

```
lg    chr    lgAndMarker(result column)
D1a   Chr01  D1a(1)
D1b   Chr02  D1a(1)(this value should be D1b(2))
```

Obviously there are somewhere wrong in such code snippet result to **all lgAndMarker result are the same**. Any help will be appreciated !

**update:**

really strange, such `lgAndMarker` column can not update no matter which way, maybe mysql lock such column or update transaction has not finished properly, but why? still unknow. But finally i drop such column and re-create it and create another temp table whose column are `id_`,`lgAndMarker_` and update `chrlg` table inner join `tmep` table outside loop. success!

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: @Crabime, once reset the `SET lgAndMarker_ ='';` after the update query

Comment: @er.irfankhan11 em, i had already done such way, but it doesn't work

Comment: once try to remove transaction.